# Change file permissions using python

Tags: permissions, python, chmod

How can I provide permission to any file from a python script?

I am developing a website, so I need to create a `.txt` file on particular location like `var/www/html/` for that I tried:

```
import subprocess
f = open('/path/to/folder/or/file.txt', 'w')
subprocess.call(['chmod', '0777', '/path/to/folder/or/file.txt'])
```

It throws `chmod: changing permissions of '/path/to/folder/or/file.txt': Operation not permitted`

How can I overcome this?

Comment: you need elevated permissions to use `chmod` unless you own the file, so you'd have to run the script with `sudo` (Are you sure you want to set `0777`? This is rarely a good idea...)

Comment: is it possible fire cmd like `sudo chmod 777 filename` from any program? if yes, how can enter password..?

Comment: Note that you can also use `os.chmod()` instead of calling a subprocess, but you still need the correct permissions to do so. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.chmod

Comment: did you solve your problem? Perhaps you could write an answer...